# Specifying growth mixture model with lcmm()

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate some growth mixture modeling results from Mplus in R, using the lcmm() package. I am having some trouble converting the model specification from a Mplus framework to a linear mixed effects model framework in R.

In Mplus, a 2-class growth mixture model was specified like this:

```
VARIABLE: NAMES ARE y1-y4;
          CLASSES = c(2);
ANALYSIS: TYPE = MIXTURE;
MODEL:
      %OVERALL%
      i s | y1@0 y2@1 y3@2 y4@3;
OUTPUT:
       TECH1;
```

In R, using the lcmm() package, I think the model specification should look something like this:

```
m1 <- hlme(y ~ time, 
           mixture = ~ time,
           random = ~ time, 
           subject = 'id',
           ng = 2,
           idiag = F,
           data = dat.long)
```

However, I am not sure if I am specifying the mixture and random arguments correctly. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Data is here: http://www.statmodel.com/usersguide/chap8/ex8.1.dat